# 2D-3D non-rigid registration

Tags: image-processing, 3d, medical

I am looking for a way to implement 2D-3D non-rigid image registration with minimal efforts and maximal reuse of existing code. So far I have found:

- http://plastimatch.org/
- http://elastix.isi.uu.nl/

However, these libraries appear to be be limited to rigid 2D-3D registration, and the non-rigidity is mandatory in my case. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139399/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Well, the problem is matching a 2D image with a 3D volume using a non-rigid transformation. I have only done some research to find a library for this, and I have come up with the ones mentioned above. I need to have ready code, since from what I have heard from experts in the field, this a rather complex problem. I only have a couple of weeks time to solve it, and it is not to be expected that I can code up a solution by myself in such a short time. I am not sure why you call this off-topic...

Comment: I'm calling it off-topic by [quoting from here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (see item 5) - I know it's not what you need, but those are the guidelines. Regarding your problem, it is perhaps complex (I have experience with 3D-3D non-rigid registration) and the only tool I know of that's widely used is [ITK](http://www.itk.org/).

Comment: OK, so now I reformulated the question. I would appreciate it, if it could be reopened. If anyone has a simple solution to this implementation problem, please say so. I do not really care whether the answer explicitly mentions a library or offers some other solution. The basic problem simply is implementing non-rigid 2D-3D registration without minimal efforts (that is, without reinventing the wheel). It is not urgent to me anymore, as the project in question was stopped for other reasons, but it could be useful to me in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Elastix does indeed support non-rigid registrations, hence the name ;)
You can find a list of some default parameter files here: http://elastix.bigr.nl/wiki/index.php/Default0 which is great if you do not want to dive into details. Check out the B-Spline text file if you want to perform a non-rigid registration.

Most important parameters are the `FixedImageDimension` and the `MovingImageDimension`. The rest should be ok.

Calling Elastix works like this:

```
elastix -m <MovingDataFile> -f <FixedDataFile> -out <OutputFolder> -p <ParameterFile> -threads <NumberOfThreads>
```

Comment: I am not referring to 2D-2D or 3D-3D registration, though, but to the 2D-3D registration mentioned here: http://elastix.isi.uu.nl/whatsnew_04_5.php. Is this also non-rigid? I am asking, because in the paper that they mention (http://goo.gl/12IoPA) they are mentioning a transformation that is described by three rotation and three translation parameters. That sounds like a rigid registration to me... Also, the example parameter files for 2D-3D registration (http://elastix.bigr.nl/wiki/index.php/Par0013) only seem to use the EulerTransform.

Comment: Ah, that complicates matters. I think you are right about the 2D-3D registration only being rigid. I've tried to change the value of parameter `Transform` to `BSplineTransform` instead of `EulerTransform` and some other changes but I was not succesful in creating a non-rigid 2D-3D registration. It might be possible with the right parameters but I do not have that much experience with Elastix, so I can't say for sure...